# Python requests - can not parse URL

Tags: python, url, python-requests

I was testing a Python program I made on a newer version of (Kali) Linux and was getting and error from doing something like:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://google.com")
```

The error said it could not parse the URL, even after I tried many variants.  I have a feeling it has something do with the version of requests.  The older & stable Linux is using requests 2.22.0 and the newer one is 2.3.0.  One of the libraries I'm using requires 2.22.0 though, so I can not upgrade.  Still can't pin down where the issue is even after looking at the requests source code.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  Downgrading to urllib3 to version 1.24.1 fixed the issue.